# Expanding continuity of a function to a certain point confusion.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity

Hello MathStackExchange.

I was given this function : Let $f$ be defind by : $ f :\mathbb{R^*} \to \mathbb{R} $ , $f(x) = \frac{(e^x-1)}{x}$.

The question was to show that there exists a function $g$ that is continuous on  $\mathbb{R}$ such that : $\forall x \in \mathbb{R^*} ; f(x) = g(x)$

What i did was , since $f(x)$ is defined on $\mathbb{R^*}$, I checked whether $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) =\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)$ , which is the case and equal to $1$. then $g(x) = $$\begin{cases}
f(x) , \forall x \in \mathbb{R^*} \\[2ex] 1,  x = 0 \\[2ex] 
\end{cases}
$

My confusion now, i was asked to give its derivative $g'$ to determine its variations, i find that $g'(x) > 0 , \forall x \in \mathbb{R^*}$.

What about for $x=0$ though? My confusion is, the derivative isn't defined on $ x = 0$ because we cannot write a zero in the denominator, but i know the function is defined on $ x = 0 $ when graphing it., I know for a function to be continuous on a point, It has to satisfy $ \lim_{x\to a} f(x)= f(a)$, But how do i know Its value if it isn't even defined there?

I was then asked to calculate the following limit: $ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{g(x)-1}{x}$, i noticed that it's on the form of : $ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0} = g'(0)$, but then again i don't know the actual value of $g'(0)$.., i know there could be other ways to calculate the limit (i used Taylor's expansion), but i'm particularly confused about this one.

I would very much appreciate it if someone can point my misunderstanding of something fundamental because i do that too much unfortunately and i very much want to correct my way of understanding these.

Sorry if it's a duplicate of an old thread but i don't see it being the case.

Comment: What do you mean by R*?

Comment: Set of real numbers except the element zero.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\ne 0$,

$$\frac {g (x)-g (0)}{x-0}=\frac {e^x-1-x}{x^2} $$

l'Hospital rule twice gives

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\frac {1}{2}=g'(0) $$

For $x\ne 0$,

$$g'(x)=\frac {xe^x-(e^x-1)}{x^2} $$

and

$$e^x=1+x+\frac {x^2}{2}(1+\epsilon(x)) $$

thus
$$\lim_{x\to0}g'(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x+x^2-x-\frac {x^2}{2}+x^2\epsilon (x))}{x^2}=\frac {1}{2} $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what if i want to use the derivative to find the limit and not vice versa?.

Comment: @Manletta, derivatives are *defined* in terms of limits, so using $g'(x_0)$ to find $\lim_{x\to x_0}(g(x)-g(x_0))/(x-x_0)$ is circular.

Comment: Suppose i wasn't asked to determine this limit, i have to go back to using the definition to get how is $ g(x) $ behaving at point $x=0$ right? and when using $g(x)$ in the limit definition formula, Which one do i use ( $g(x) = 1$ or $g(x) = f(x) $ , i know i have to use $g(x) = f(x)$, but why? @Raptor

Comment: By definition, $g(x)=f(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb R^*$. This justifies @Salahamam_Fatima's first equation.

Comment: @Manletta Please look the lines i added.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima, I think i wasn't able to express what i want in the right way,Sorry for that, I'm not really looking for the value of the limit, i already mentioned that i used Taylor's expansion to find the limit :(, Suppose i wasn't asked to find this limit,but $g$'s variations, I know that g(x) is continuous in $\mathbb {R}$, I find $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}/0$ , $g'(x) > 0$, but what about the point $0$? My question is, do i always have to check the limit at the point that the formula of $g'(x)$ is not defined in?, because continuity doesn't imply derivability.

Comment: Never mind, I think i'm overcomplicating the problem, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Well!.....Since $g(x)$ has been defined anywhere and is similarly continuous over $R$ you can observe that $g(x)=\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^n\over{(n+1)!}}$ and then $g^{'}(0)={1\over 2}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i do not have a problem with calculating $g'(0)$, i'm trying to understand what does it mean to have a value at $x=0$ but not being able to write it out in the formula i.e not writing the zero in the denominator.